# Script doesn work: Image Changing When Click jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I have a little problem with my test-site i'm making.

I love experimenting with Javascript but i'm getting stuck on this little code...

**What i'm trying to reach:**

*When you click on a picture below, the picture will become visible in the main of the page, and also in the background. When you click in the main of the page ( where the picture is visible ), it will automaticly go to the next one.*

**What I have right now:**

*I already made a popup window, and now starting the pictures. I already inserted a code, but it don't seem to open very well. I tried alot but it's still not working.*

**jQuery**

*What I have tried to do is:*

```
$('#photo').fadeIn();
$("#gallery ul li").on("click", function() {
var selector = '#photo[src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]';

$(".selected").hide();

$('selector').fadeIn();
return false;
});

$('#gallery ul li').on('click', function() {
$("#photo").hide();
var next = $(this).next();
if (next.length > 0) {
    next.fadeIn();    
} else {
    $('.selected').fadeIn();
}
return false;
});
```

Also I have made a **jsFiddle** where I have input the HTML & CSS.

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yahitchu/GWtHN/)

I want to create this:

### [This](http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/6/)

Comment: Quick question:  Why are you recreating the wheel when you could just use an image carousel?  There are quite a few made for jquery already that handle issues/configurations you wouldn't think of.

Comment: I need to use the HTML and CSS which is given to me. So I am trying to find a fitting code which makes it all work. I did try a lot of codes which are already only, but when I put my div's in the code nothing happens. So that is why 'I am recreating the wheel'. I am sorry to put a question here which is so obvious, but I get stuck.